# How to use the fat-jar generated by mvn package when you run spring-boot:run?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In some scenarios, you need to use some elements included in the fat jar, like:

- MANIFEST
- Dependency jars

But using the the command: `mvn spring-boot:run` doesn´t run the application using that way and it is only possible to find that elements if you execute:

```
mvn package
java -jar target/YOUR_APPLICATION_AS_FAT_JAR.jar
```

Does exist any configuration to use spring-boot:run using as an input the fat jar?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The purpose of `mvn spring-boot:run` goal is to provide the option to developer to run application when IDE fails build/discover all required dependencies, what is your goal?

Comment: Hi Andrey, when you execute the target spring-boot:run, the developer are running the application but not exactly in the same way that later it will be used. If the application requires to read some internals file like the MANIFEST or get access to the libraries, it is not possible to execute that code.